# PCICt not working with day 31 of month

Tags: r, lubridate

I am using PCICt to get the birth dates of individuals using the 360 day calendar. However, when I run it, it seems like dates that have the day "31" do not work. There might be another problem, but this is what it seems like to me, as it returns the following error when it hits such numbers:

```
Error in missing(res) : 'missing' can only be used for arguments
```

Here is my code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  as.PCICt(df$date[i], cal = "360_day"))
}
```

Thanks!

edit:
I am essentially taking them and subtracting by another date to find the age of the individual.
This is the code I wrote for that task:

```
  df$age[i] <- as.numeric((as.PCICt(df$date[i],cal ="360_day") as.PCICt(df$dob[i],"360_day"))/86400)/360
```

Comment: What format is df in? I tried `as.PCICt` on a POSIXct object of 2017-01-31 EST, and got `"2017-02-01 05:00:24"`

Comment: Hi doviod. They are characters set up as "YYYY-MM-DD". I am essentially taking them and subtracting by another date to find the age of the individual.

Comment: Why do you need to use a 360 day calendar, then? Also, if you just subtract two `Date` objects one from the other, you should get the distance in days in a "difftime" class object:

`> d1<-as.Date("2017-10-30")
> d2<-as.Date("1978-12-15")
> d1-d2
Time difference of 14199 days
> str(d1-d2)
Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:1] 14199
  ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "days"`

I recently started working on a package that further translates this into months or years with its own print method, you can find it on github at dubikan/humanize

Comment: In public health, that is the most efficient way to calculate the age from what I understand. I used difftime, but, unfortunately, I did not get the results I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running them through `as.POSIXct()` first. Seems to work for me:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  as.PCICt(as.POSIXct(df$date[i]), cal = "360_day"))
}
```

When you give it a character object, it just takes that value directly as a 360 day calendar value, it doesn't convert it from a regular calendar to a 360-day one. So if you want to input a 365-day calendar format, you first have to pass it through `as.POSIXct()` so `as.PCICt()` knows it needs to convert it from 365 to 360 calendar.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! It seems like, for some reason, dates before 1970 are not working and NA is returning. Do you have an idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Hello! I figured out the solution for anyone also having this problem. To account for before 1970 you must use POSIXlt, so it would be:                            for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  as.PCICt(as.POSIXlt(df$date[i]), cal = "360_day"))
}      Thanks a lot for everyone's help!